# Android Room Database Table is not updating

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to update a value from my Table using RX2 and room.

My item is

```java
@Entity(tableName = "myCustomTable")
public class MyItem  {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    @SerializedName("item_id")
    private Long item_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "country")
    @SerializedName("country")
    private String value;

    @SerializedName("image")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    private String image;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude")
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    private Double latitude;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "longitude")
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    private Double longitude;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "valid")
    private boolean valid;

    public MyItem (Long item_id, String name, String value, String image, Double latitude, Double longitude, boolean valid) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.image = image;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.valid = true;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public Long getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

My query is this:

```java
@Dao
public interface CustomDao {
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  void insertItem(MyItem item);

  @Query("UPDATE myCustomTable SET valid = :isValid WHERE item_id= :id")
  void flagQueued(long id, boolean isValid);
}
```

By default the valid is true;

This will be called and converted to a completable by the database implementation

```java
public class LocalDataSource implements DataSource {
  private CustomDao customDao;

  @Inject
  public LocalPupilDataSource(CustomDao customDao) {
    this.customDao = customDao;
  }

  public Completable flagQueued(long id) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> customDao.flagQueued(id,false));
  }
}
```

And eventually, I call the flagQueued method by a subscriber. This subscriber is responding with a successful completion.

```java
mCompositeDisposable.add(viewModel.deleteItem(id)
  .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
  .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
  .subscribe(() -> Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_layout),
    R.string.user_removed, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), error -> Timber.e(error,error.getMessage()) ) );
```

Unfortunately, the value is not being updated. Of course, the ID exists in the table.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The result is 1 @pskink

Comment: is item_id a long? Maybe you're comparing a long with a different data type in your query? Post MyItem class please

Comment: Hi @NicolaGallazzi. Just updated the question with the Myitem class

Comment: It looks good. You can look inside your database with this tool https://sqlitebrowser.org/. Use device file explorer in Android Studio and look to data/data/yourapppackageid to find the database

Comment: I think there is a space in table name @Entity(tableName = "myCustomTable "). Can you check that?

Comment: Checked this already @AmitKumar. This is not the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: It was successful indeed @pskink. I cannot see any table visible, by the preview or through executing the command select * .
This is funny, since I am offline on my emulator, and I fetch data from the db

Comment: @pskink There is no schema declared in the database. Strange.

Comment: @pskink I copy the the database path from the emulator, I open the sqlite browser, I open a new database and I select the mytestDatabase.db file, and I open it.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. After hours of debugging.

The default value I assign on the constructor `this.valid = true;` for some reason broke the QUERY.

So the solution is just to remove the fault value, and assign my desired value to the Item when I am about to insert it into the table.

Is there any GitHub repo for room where I could post the issue ?

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, insertion works fine but update won't work idk Y
Its such a horrible bug.. won't even throw any error